# Can't delete rows from DataTable based on another DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, row

I have two `DataTable`s.

`distinct`:

```
+-------+-------+
| host  | count |
+-------+-------+
| comp1 |     2 |
+-------+-------+
| comp2 |     3 |
+-------+-------+
| comp3 |     2 |
+-------+-------+
```

`t`:

```
+----+-------+
| id |  host |
+----+-------+
| 1  | comp1 |
+----+-------+
| 2  | comp2 |
+----+-------+
| 3  | comp1 |
+----+-------+
| 4  | comp3 |
+----+-------+
| 5  | comp1 |
+----+-------+
| 6  | comp3 |
+----+-------+
```

I want to remove all rows from `t` which contains the computername having less than `3` in `count` column in `distinct` table. The code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < distinct.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(distinct.Rows[i][1]) < 3)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in t.Select())
        {
            if (row[1].ToString() == distinct.Rows[i][0].ToString())
            {
                row.Delete();
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

But it does nothing. If I compare the content of `t` before the above code and after, it's just the same. what am I missing here?

Comment: you cannot delete row like that. you need to do `DataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(Index)` or `DataTable.Rows.Remove(Datarow)` in you case replace `row.Delete();` with `t.Rows.Remove(row);`

Comment: Yeah, you're rigth. It's working that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer following link

[How To Compare and delete datatable row using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/686406/How-To-Compare-and-delete-datatable-row-using-Csha)